# CakePHP 1.3: extending class unable to find its parent model PHP file

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

In the class declaration line of the model (.php) files, I'm trying to extend off of a different class then `AppModel`. Let's say I have some  models, including `Model`, `ModelOrder`, and `ModelLastShipment`, etc. And yes, "Model" is a made up name for the sake of generalization.

`Model` does not use a table and does not have any table association. It extends `AppModel`. It has some basic functions that I'd like `ModelOrder` and `ModelLastShipment` (and other `Model...` classes) to inherit. The problem is that while `ModelOrder` can be extended (i.e. `class ModelOrder extends Model {...}`), I'm unable to do the same with the following because of a missing file error.

model_last_shipment.php:

```
class ModelLastShipment extends Model {...}
```

This returns the error,

```
Fatal error: Class 'Model' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_app\app\models\model_last_shipment.php on line 3
```

Including `include_once('model.php')` before the declaration solves this issue, but why does the extension work for `ModelOrder` without explicit inlcusion but not for `ModelLastShipment`?

Please let me know if there is more information needed to resolve this. There are many articles and posts regarding this sort of error, but I've yet to find out why I'm getting this error for one and not for another.

Comment: You should always extend the AppModel, and make sure the parent class is loaded - in 1.3 I guess you need App::import() for that.

Comment: Just updated the post. `Model` extends the `AppModel` (of course!).

Comment: No, the other way around :) And: `class ModelLastShipment extends AppModel` then.

Comment: But I want to extended off of `Model` so `ModelLastShipment` inherits some properties from `Model`. These are properties that aren't appropriate for `AppModel`.

Answer (score 1):

> Let's say I have some models, including Model

### It's impossible to create a class named "Model"

[Model](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/cake/libs/model/model.php) is a core class. If you create a class named Model, it with either not be loaded (because the class `Model` already exists) or cause fatal behavior - possibly "at random".

The class structure in the question is:

```
Overloadable (Cake)
    Model (Cake)
        AppModel (App)
            Model (App) <- problem
```

That cannot work. Class names *must* be unique and `Model` is a core class.

> Including include_once('model.php') before the declaration solves this issue

Are these model class names made up? As stated above that isn't possible with a class named `Model`.

### Intermediary class models are not automatically loaded

These are the only model classes that are loaded automatically in Cake 1.3:

- Model
- AppModel
- AppModel (when appropriate)

If the class hierarchy of your models is such that there are more intermediary classes - they need to be loaded explicitly:

```
<?php
App::import('Model', 'SomethingElse');

class NotNamedModel extends SomethingElse {
```

Comment: I've -1 the question as it's obvious the class names are made up such that the question is of no use to any future readers. Please _always_ use real names. I'll update my answer when the question is updated.

Comment: I was thinking the opposite that it would be more useful to use a generic name for generalization, but I admit "Model" was a poor choice  as you described. I've updated to add to my post but won't change the content as I've already made comments with reference.

Comment: Now, my question is that I don't understand why one class can extend "Model" without `App::import()` while another class can't. According to your answer it, the latter is actually normal. I'll look to see if all of the functions work properly.